# 403 Error while creating API through Publisher API in Wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

i am getting 403 forbideen error for below curl command,

Step1: Get the token

```
{
    "access_token": "*********************c",
    "scope": "am_application_scope apim:api_create apim:api_view",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Step 2:

````
curl --location --request POST 'https://PublisherDNS/api/am/publisher/v1/apis' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer *************************' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=508DADCDB2B1F4CF8C0E459C838AE10C; requestedURI=../../api/am/publisher/v1/apis' \
--data-raw '{
  "name": "PizzaShackAPI",
  "description": "This is a simple API for Pizza Shack online pizza delivery store.",
  "context": "pizza",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  
} ```
````

Comment: What is the APIM version you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with **v1.0** instead of v1 in your URL? (Also, v0.15 should be working as well)

Comment: why documentation says v1 not v1.0, do you guys test features before publishing it?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Even though the topic says it's v1 all the examples (the cURL commands that will be generated when clicking TryOut in [1]) and URLs in [1] have it as v1.0. 



[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/develop/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v1/publisher-v1/